# How to select all data in a row in the same day by using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
date        Label
2021-12-12    0
2021-12-12    0
2021-12-12    1
2021-12-12    0
2021-12-13    1
2021-12-13    1
2021-12-14    1
```

I want to the lines in the same day become to a vector, such as in 2021-12-12 I'll have a vector [0,0,1,0], 2021-12-13 is [1,1],...
How can I do that by using pandas?
Thank you everybody!

Comment: `df.groupby('date').agg(list)`

Comment: it works, thank you so much^^